# How to parse_dates for the Imported CSV File in google colab ?? the CSV file is imported from the Local drive

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, google-colaboratory

**In Google Colab I have imported the CSV file from local drive, using the below code :**

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

**then to read the CSV file to parse_date I have the below code :**

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['Auto.csv'], parse_dates = ['Date'],date_parser=parse))
print(df)
```

**it show's the error message as below :**

```
TypeError: StringIO() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

**But when importing file from github it works good for example shown below :**

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/master/dataset/electricity_consumption.csv', parse_dates = ['Bill_Date'],date_parser=parse)    #this code works good from github
```

**so I want to parse_dates for the csv file imported from the Local drive ??? Kindly help me on this???**

Data set looks like this :

[image]

Comment: You messed up the parentheses. Should have been `io.StringIO(uploaded['Auto.csv']),` instead of `io.StringIO(uploaded['Auto.csv'],`.

Comment: It did not work after adding the parentheses and showing error message as :- initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Comment: @QuangHoang It did not work after adding the parentheses and showing error message as :- initial_value must be str or None, not bytes